# iOS MagicalRecord mystery. Why does my data reappear on restart after truncateAll?

Tags: ios, uitableview, magicalrecord

I've got a tiny app using Core Data via MagicalRecord for the purpose of learning how to group activities by categories and display the data in a grouped tableview. Accordingly, I've got two entities, only one of which is being used here. It's called ListActivity, and has two attributes, "name" and "category," both strings.

Putting aside the difficulty I'm having understanding the workings of the various grouping and sorting methods provided in MR, I added a "TruncateAll" button to simply clear the slate so I can reenter data.

Here's the IBAction method for that button:

```
- (IBAction)dumpMemory:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [ListActivity MR_truncateAll];
    [self refreshData];
}
```

Here's the peculiar thing: The button action wipes the tableview (and presumably the store) clean, as expected.

However, if I kill the sim via the "Stop" button in Xcode, then restart it, **all the data reappears in the tableview**. Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate:

**After entering data:**

[image]

**After hitting the TruncateAll button:**

[image]

**After killing, then restarting, the data mysteriously reappears:**

[image]

**However, if I kill the app in the sim:**

[image]

**When it restarts, the slate is clean:**

[image]

Can someone with MagicalRecord experience please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

OK, thanks to all who answered! Everybody immediately saw my mistake. I modified my IBAction method like so:

```
- (IBAction)dumpMemory:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [ListActivity MR_truncateAllInContext:localContext];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    [self refreshData];
}
```

and now things work perfectly!

Many thanks!

Comment: When are you saving (calling some variation of MR_save)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is very common with `MagicalRecord` development. By main tutorial, the `MagicalRecord` only saves context when app is put into background. So if you kill the app before `applicationDidEnterBackground` method is called in the Application Delegate, the truncate will not be saving.

When you remove the application from simulator, all application data is deleted.

To solve this problem, make sure you call `MagicalRecord`'s `save` method on appropriate place, if you are only testing, it can be in the `IBAction` of the Truncate All button.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, saving to permanent storage in background is usually the way to go. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to *save* the managed object context, so that the changes do
not persist across an application restart.